# Converting "Mon March 28 2016 23:59:59 GMT -0600 (CENTRAL DAYLIGHT TIME)" TO "2016-03-28 23:59:59" (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

How do I convert:

> "Mon March 28 2016 23:59:59 GMT -0600 (CENTRAL DAYLIGHT TIME)"

TO

> "2016-03-28 23:59:59" (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var h = addZero(d.getHours());
    var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
    var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
    x.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}


function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear(),
          h = addZero(d.getHours()),
     m = addZero(d.getMinutes()),
     s = addZero(d.getSeconds());

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-')+" "+[h,m,s].join(':');
}
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML =  formatDate('Mon March 28 2016 23:59:59 GMT -0600 (CENTRAL DAYLIGHT TIME)') ;
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/PrabuB/61cycmLs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var d=your date;
var actualDate=d.toLocaleString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: localsestring is not giving consistent results with all browsers. i may not use the localeString

Comment: this will not vary from browser to browser although it will be vary if culture is different

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for date-time conversion

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ,

In ur view,

```
columns.Bound("YOUR MODEL").Format("
{0:n6}").ClientTemplate("#=SAMPLEDATEDISPLAY#").Title("Sample Date");
```

In ur model,

```
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SAMPLEDATE{ get; set; }

    public string SAMPLEDATEDISPLAY{ get { return SAMPLEDATE.HasValue ? SAMPLEDATE.Value.ToString() : string.Empty; } }
```

Please feedback :)